# UIDocumentStateChangedNotification detect delete item

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud, uidocument

i want know if it's possible with the `UIDocumentStateChangedNotification` detect if an item is deleted, if not, how i can detect if a item is deleted from the cloud?

Answer (score 0):

Add an observer for UIDocumentStateChangedNotification to your viewDidLoad.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
        addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(itemHasChanged:)
        name:UIDocumentStateChangedNotification
        object:nil];
```

If the documentState of a changed object is set to UIDocumentStateSavingError, then it was deleted.

```
-(void) itemHasChanged:(id)sender {
    UIDocument *itemDoc = [sender object]; 

    if ([itemDoc documentState] == UIDocumentStateSavingError) {
      // your code to handle a deleted document goes here
      // in my case I remove that object from my array of current objects.
    }
}
```